# Importing HTML from file into PHP variable

Tags: php, html

I am trying to parse some HTML from files into a PHP variable to send across HTML email, but I am struggling. It doesn't output anything at all when loaded. Only the submit button is echoed. What am I doing wrong? I know it's probably a lot, but can someone please advise me on how to get this to work?

I will end up using AJAX for the submit button so the page isn't reloaded, but the content (at the moment) isn't even displaying. It's a lot of code, so I decided to break it up into files to make it easier to read and easier to inject.

```
<?php

// Setting mail options

$to = $_POST["clientemail"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];

// Are we debugging?

$debug = true;

// Set content-type header for sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: CodexWorld<"postmaster@intel-web.co.uk">' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: b.ravetta@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: admin@intel-web.co.uk' . "\r\n";

// Place all HTML content into one big fucking message.
$head = file_get_contents("head.html");
$body = file_get_contents("body.html");
$footnotes = file_get_contents("footer.html"); 

if($_POST["packageid"] == 1)
    {
        $content = file_get_contents("fb.html"); 
    }
    if($_POST["packageid"] == 2)
    {
        $content = file_get_contents("aw.html"); 
    }
    if($_POST["packageid"] == 3)
    {
        $content = file_get_contents("mobi.html"); 
    };

$messagecontent = 

    echo $head;

    echo $body;

    echo $content;

    echo $footnotes;

;

// Where the message content ends.

echo "<form method='POST' action=''>
<input type='submit' name='sendmail'  value='Send Email'>
</form>";

if (isset($_POST['sendmail']))  
   if(mail($to,$subject,$messagecontent,$headers)):
    $successMsg = 'Email has sent successfully.';
else:
    $errorMsg = 'Email sending fail.';
endif;

// Debug Shit
if ($debug)
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting("E_STRICT")
?>
```

Comment: I'm no PHP expert, so I could be wrong, but looks to me like there's a syntax error with the `$messagecontent = ` line. You have the assignment operator followed by a statement (`echo $head;`). Is something missing there?

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that you even get a submit button at all. Because

```
$messagecontent = 


    echo $head;

    echo $body;

    echo $content;

    echo $footnotes;

;
```

should actually raise a syntax error for an unexpected T_ECHO.

If you want to concatenate a string, that's how you do it:

```
$messagecontent = $head . $body . $content . $footnotes;
```

If you fix that, you will still only get the submit button after submitting the form, because while you will send the mail, you do nothing with your success / error message. You might want to do something like

```
if (isset($_POST['sendmail'])) {  
    if(mail($to,$subject,$messagecontent,$headers)) {
        $successMsg = 'Email has sent successfully.';
        echo $successMsg;
    } else {
        $errorMsg = 'Email sending fail.';
        echo $errorMsg;
    }
}
```

(Note: I also changed the syntax of your if statements to an accepted standard. see http://www.php-fig.org/psr/)

Also, you might want to change the error reporting settings in the php.ini and not in the file. Because if you do have a parse error, you won't see it (because the file can't be parsed and so `display_errors` won't get set to 1.

Comment: Thanks man, yes I wasn't focusing much energy on the submit button at the moment I was jut trying to grasp the concept of getting the content from the external files to display. How would I do this??

Comment: You load the content of the files into variables, then you concatenate them into `$messagecontent`. If you want to display it, simply `echo $messagecontent;`

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out after I wrote it. Damn man seriously, been working on this script for so many days and this was what was holding me back. Thanks a lot!